# How to merge hash of arrays?

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
[
 {a => 1, b => { c => 1, d => 1}},
 {a => 1, b => { c => 1, d => 2}},
 {a => 1, b => { c => 2, d => 2}},
 {a => 2, b => { c => 1, d => 1}},
]
```

I want to change it to this:

```
[
 {a => 1, b => [{ c => 1, d => [1, 2]}, { c => 2, d => [2]}]},
 {a => 2, b=> [ { c=> 1, d => [1] } ]}
]
```

Rules/Requirements:

- Hashes of same value of `a` go to one hash
- `b` should be an array of `{c => , d =>}`
- `d` should be an array
- `d` with same value of `c` go to same array

Comment: Do you mean `"a"=>1` or `:a => 1`? If not, is `a` a local variable or a method? What is the rule that results in `d => [2]` instead of `d => 2` and `d => [1]` instead of `d => 1`, considering that you have `a => 1`, `c => 1`, etc.?

Comment: Your question is problematic because the rules for producing the output are not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. It is very explicit, so it would not generalize to other hash structures.

```
hashes = [
 {:a => 1, :b => { :c => 1, :d => 1}},
 {:a => 1, :b => { :c => 1, :d => 2}},
 {:a => 1, :b => { :c => 2, :d => 2}},
 {:a => 2, :b => { :c => 1, :d => 1}},
]

a_values = {}
hashes.each do |hash|
  a_value = hash[:a]
  a_values[a_value] ||= {}

  c_value = hash[:b][:c]
  a_values[a_value][c_value] ||= { :c => c_value, :d => [] }

  d_value = hash[:b][:d]
  a_values[a_value][c_value][:d].push(d_value)
end

# Now aggregate the results
results = a_values.map do |a_value, c_hashes|
  b_arr = c_hashes.map { |c_value, c_hash| c_hash }
  { :a => a_value, :b => b_arr }
end
```

And here is the output:

```
[
  {:a=>1, :b=>[{:c=>1, :d=>[1, 2]}, {:c=>2, :d=>[2]}]}, 
  {:a=>2, :b=>[{:c=>1, :d=>[1]}]}
]
```